# Can't get a reference to use IISOle object in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7

I am trying to get a reference to the Active DS IIS Namespace Provider in Visual Studio .NET. This reference will enable me to use the IISOle namespace....

I have tried adding the reference by doing the following steps in Visual Studio 2010:

1. Add References
2. COM

In my list of references I can only see the "Active DS Type Library", this does not give me the reference I need to use IISOle. I have read that you need to **"Active DS IIS Namespace Provider"** but it does not appear in my list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows 7 you must add IIS6 extensions:

1. In "Control Panel", go to "Programs and Features", "Turn Windows features on or off" and scope out everything under IIS, including the IIS 6 stuff.
2. Make sure that the feature "IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility" is checked, found under "Internet Information Services" > "Web Management Tools" > "IIS 6 Management Compatibility".

[image: Windows Features IIS 6 Management Compatibility options from Windows 10]

3. Then you can add these COM references to your VS2010 project:

   - Active DS IIS Extension Dll
   - Active DS IIS Namespace Provider

And you are done! :-)

Comment: Superb. thank you!
I would never have figured this out an my own!